# asp.net read from other local resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, localization

I have local resources files like on screenshot:

[image]

How can I read local resource data of AddCustomer page in Default.aspx page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At last found it:

```
HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(virtualPath, resourceKey)
```

Comment: And to get from Global resource file `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(className, resourceKey)`

Comment: And here's how you use it: HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/MyPage.aspx", "Label1Resource1.Text");

Answer (score 2):

Read the file in a StreamReader.

```
StreamReader SR;
SR = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/App_globalResources/Litware.resx"));
string str = SR.ReadToEnd();
SR.Close();
```

Comment: @ihorko Sure. This would be an inefficient way to do it, but I thought you just wanted to read the file. You could use the XMLTextReader class.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should consider using a global resource file if it makes sense, and access it anywhere in a Page through Resources.MyGlobalResxFile.MyString [as you may have already read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx).

Otherwise I believe you should avoid this if you are considering to access a local resource on a different page only because it so happens that a couple of strings are the same. You are better off I think if you just duplicate those strings and keep resource dependencies on each page separate from one another and thus cleaner to maintain

Comment: "it so happens that a couple of strings are the same" - if there are some same strings it doesn't work for the page I read from! I pass the path to file which I read the data from, so it works perfect!